# Model and conroller relationship laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new at laravel, and i have some problem to manage relationship with model and controller.

I have indexcontroller, where called:

```
$usersModel = new \App\Models\Users();
if ($usersModel->checkOnExistsByEmail($params['user_email'])){
     //...find it
}
```

Model file:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model {
    protected $table = 'users_data';

    public function scopeCheckOnExistsByEmail($query,$email){

        $count = $query->where('user_email','=',$email)->count();
        if ($count == 0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

After that i've got an a error:

```
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string
```

Could someone explain whats i do wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: Let the controller handle the logic not the model

Comment: `scopes` can't be converted to boolean, `scopes` must return builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper Model code is:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model {
    protected $table = 'users_data';

    public function checkOnExistsByEmail($email){   
        return (bool)$this->where('email', $email)->first();
    }

}
```

You dont need to use scopes.

Answer (score 1):

First return the value from controller for verify,

```
    return $params['user_email'];
```

If you get answer, then try follow below codes.

You don't need to return in the model function

You need to use,

```
    if(count($usersModel->checkOnExistsByEmail($params['user_email']) > 0)) { //.... }
```

in model only use,

```
    $query->where('email', $email);
```

or You are using count in function, then

```
    if($usersModel->checkOnExistsByEmail($params['user_email']) > 0) { //.... }
```

I think, this will help you.